# MySQL Query returns incorrect Week Number

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue trying to query week numbers through a mysql query.

This is an example of the issue

August 2, 2015 is a Sunday and according to everywhere I've checked, by NON-ISO standard, it should belong to Week 32 (week 31 by ISO Standard) but my queries either give me, Week 30 (Non-ISO) or Week 31 (ISO). I need Sundays to be the first day of the week.

```
WEEK('2015-8-2', 0) // Returns 31
WEEK('2015-8-2', 2) // Returns 31
WEEK('2015-8-2', 4) // Returns 31
WEEK('2015-8-2', 6) // Returns 31
```

Mode 1, 3, 5, 7 return 30 for August 2, 2015.

I've also used WEEKOFYEAR('2015-8-2') and it also returns 31.

I'm clueless as to why it won't give me 32 without having to add a +1 to the query.

```
WEEKOFYEAR('2015-8-2') + 1
```

So is it safe to do a WEEKOFYEAR(date) + 1 or WEEK(date, 2) + 1 query?

Am I wrong into thinking that 8/2/2015 is Week 32 by NON-ISO Standard?

Comment: why not just week() mode 0 ?

Comment: Because it still returns 31 and not 32.

Comment: that is to be expected

Comment: What's a "non ISO standard"? It's like a black americano with milk

Answer (score 2):

Sunday is always the first day of the week. We agree on that. (Except for the first week :>)

Here is the [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) page for week().

Jan 1 2015 was a Thursday. The first Sunday was Jan 4, 2015.

These all return 0:

```
select WEEK('2015-1-1', 0);
select WEEK('2015-1-2', 0);
select WEEK('2015-1-3', 0);
```

These all return 1:

```
select WEEK('2015-1-4', 0);
select WEEK('2015-1-5', 0);
select WEEK('2015-1-6', 0);
select WEEK('2015-1-7', 0);
select WEEK('2015-1-8', 0);
select WEEK('2015-1-9', 0);
select WEEK('2015-1-10', 0);
```

That is the nature of mode 0.

From the Manual:

> If the week containing January 1 has 4 or more days in the new year,
>   it is week 1.
>
> Otherwise, it is the last week of the previous year, and the next week
>   is week 1.

But regardless, the manual page shows the range always 0 to 53 for mode 0.

```
select WEEK('2013-12-31', 0); -- 52
select WEEK('2014-12-31', 0); -- 52
select WEEK('2015-12-31', 0); -- 52
select WEEK('2016-12-31', 0); -- 52
select WEEK('2017-12-31', 0); -- 53  < ----- Look at me !
select WEEK('2018-12-31', 0); -- 52
select WEEK('2019-12-31', 0); -- 52

select WEEK('2013-01-01', 0); -- 0
select WEEK('2014-01-01', 0); -- 0
select WEEK('2015-01-01', 0); -- 0
select WEEK('2016-01-01', 0); -- 0
select WEEK('2017-01-01', 0); -- 1  < ----- Look at me !
select WEEK('2018-01-01', 0); -- 0
select WEEK('2019-01-01', 0); -- 0
```

Edit:

### Mode 3

```
select WEEK('2014-12-21', 3); -- 51 Sun
select WEEK('2014-12-22', 3); -- 52 Monday
select WEEK('2014-12-28', 3); -- 52 Sunday
select WEEK('2014-12-29', 3); -- 1 Monday
select WEEK('2014-12-30', 3); -- 1 T
select WEEK('2014-12-31', 3); -- 1 W
select WEEK('2015-01-01', 3); -- 1 T
select WEEK('2015-01-02', 3); -- 1 F
select WEEK('2015-01-03', 3); -- 1 Sat
select WEEK('2015-01-04', 3); -- 1 Sunday
select WEEK('2015-01-05', 3); -- 2 Monday
```

Comment: I'm following you and I understand that but that is based on ISO Standard, which according to such Standard, the last week of 2014 (week 52) was from 12/22/14 to 12/28/14 (Monday) and 12/21/14 to 12/27/14 (Sunday). Since there shouldn't be a Week 53, the first week of 2015 should have been 12/29/14-1/4/15 (Monday) or 12/28/14-1/3/15 (Sunday)... Or I am wrong? This means that 8/2/15 should be week 32 with Sunday as first day of the week and 8/3/15 with Monday as first day of the week. am I making sense?

Comment: ok looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) so I can get up to speed with Mondays, sorry 396. Ok, so, it looks like it has to be mode 3 or 7, but most likely mode 3 that starts on Monday and has the first Thursday, right ?

Comment: It's alright. I've been wrecking my head with this and I've been reading quite a bit but no cigar yet. I need the first day of the week to be Sunday, not Monday, which is where my issue is. Mode 3 works with Monday as first day of the week. Mode 0 assumes that the first Week of 2015 started on 1/4/15 and not 12/28/15 and with Mode 0, Week 32 starts on 8/9/2015.

Comment: look at the Edit at end for Mode 3. sorry I have been so dense

Comment: oh gotcha u want Sunday first day ok. But Sunday is not ISO standard, no ?

Comment: Yes, I need it to be Sunday. The strange thing is that Mode 2 should use Sunday as the first day of the week but it's taking the first Sunday of January 2015 as the first day of the week and not December 28. I'm starting to think that I'll need a custom query for this.

Comment: that was my thought sorry. this may sound dumb, but I know people that have custom lookup tables (few thousand rows) for custom purposes. you could maintain one over time, three columns: week #, begin, end. so 50ish per year. lame i know, but still exceedingly fast.

Answer (score 2):

So I finally gave up on trying to make each year count only 52 weeks as there will always be a year with 53 weeks (or just one extra day) every 5.6 years.

So, to make my life easier and follow up with the standard (except that I need the week to always start on Sunday instead of Monday), I'm running the following query.

```
YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY), 3);
```

what this does is that it returns the week number along with the year is corresponds to but using Sunday as the first day of the week instead of monday. For example.

```
YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD('2015-8-9', INTERVAL 1 DAY, 3)
```

returns

```
201532
```

Now this isn't the best way to do it as I'm sure there are probably other and more accurate ways but this one works. So every time I pick a Sunday, it adds one extra day to the result of the query which bring the date to Monday which by ISO Standard, is the first day of the week.

Another way to do it is as follows.

```
IF(DAYOFWEEK(Date) = 1, YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY), 3), YEARWEEK(date, 3))
```

This way, It will only add the extra day, when the date queried is a Sunday.

I'm going to opt for the second method as I find it to be more accurate since Monday will always belong to the week in question.

Hope this helps others.